# My javascript loop/ while statement code doesn't work, please help me identify my problem

Tags: javascript

So apparently according to my teacher I need to refine my syntax and logic. It doesn't make any sense (my code and my thoughts about this whole javascript thing)

```
var die = Math.random() * 6;        // generate a random number

die = Math.ceil( die );     // round it to between 1 and 6

var counter = 1;

var x = prompt( "What is your first guess?"); // fill x variable with the guess.  Then compare the value in die to the value in x.  What would that code be?


        while (counter < 3)
        if (x==die)
        {alert "Well done you win!"}
        break;
        }
        else {
        prompt ("Sorry.  Not the right answer.  Try again");
        counter == counter+1;
        }

var counter = counter+1;

var y = prompt("What is your second guess?"); // second x value

        while (counter ==2)
        if (y==die)
        {alert "Well done"}
        break;
        }
        else{
        prompt ("Sorry, you were wrong. Last try.");
        counter == counter+1;
        }

var counter = counter+1;


        var z = prompt("What is your third guess?"); // third x value

        while (counter == 3)
        if (z==die)
        {alert "Well done"}
        break;
        }
        else{
        prompt ("Sorry, you lost.");
        break;
        }
```

Comment: Your `}` count is not matching the count of `{`

Comment: First off, your code doesn't run because you have syntax errors with **while**, **if**, **alert** and unmatched braces. Second, whenever you see so much repetitive code, it means you're doing something wrong (not sure if you know the DRY principle - Don't Repeat Yourself). Third, you don't need a while statement for every instance. Fourth, you're mixing the assignment operator with the comparison operator (=, ==). And fifth, use alert to show a message, and prompt to get user input.

Comment: Please format your code properly; it makes it much easier for us to debug visually

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is probably in the line

```
counter == counter+1;
```

It should an assignment expression

```
counter = counter + 1;
```

#### Using `while` loop

A good way to do that is store the strings in a array and then use them in single `while` loop.

```js
let arr = ["first","second","third"];
let die = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
console.log(die);
let counter = 0;
while(counter < 3){
  let input = prompt("What is your " + arr[counter] + " guess?");
  if(+input === die){ // +input converts input into a number here
    alert("You win");
    break;
  }
  else{
    alert("Sorry try again");
  }
  counter++;
}
```

#### Using `for` loop

I would do it using `for` loop. Because the `counter` variable is increasing one by one each time.

```js
let arr = ["first","second","third"];
let die = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
console.log(die);

for(let i = 0;i<3;i++){
  let input = prompt("What is your " + arr[i] + " guess?");
  if(+input === die){ // +input converts input into a number here
    alert("You win");
    break;
  }
  alert("Sorry try again");
}
```

#### Using `for..of`

We already have an array of length `3` `["first","second","third"]`. So we don't need to create a variable for loop and then use it. We can clean up the code the using `for..of`. I also used template string for a perfect solution

```js
let arr = ["first","second","third"];
let die = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
console.log(die);

for(let x of arr){
  let input = prompt(`What is your ${x} guess?`);
  if(+input === die){ // +input converts input into a number here
    alert("You win");
    break;
  }
  alert("Sorry try again");
}
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind me editing it to make it more readable for a beginner.